# PHP function to check if a variable exist or not outside of a function

Tags: php

I am in need of a PHP function to check that a variable exist or not outside of function. If it does not exist, then assign a default value to it.

The function will be something like: `function if_exist($argument, $default = '')` where `$argument` will be any variable outside the function. It can be a variable's variable, and `$default` will be the default value of the variable if the variable doesn't exist.

***Please avoid using global scope in the function***, because I heard that it's not good for a site's security.

Comment: Using globals is not necessarily related to security (don't shout), but it makes the code much more difficult to understand and to maintain...

Comment: **Global scope has little to nothing to do with security.** Purists don't like global scope simply because they feel it pollutes the namespace and makes a program hard to maintain. If you don't abuse of it, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `$argument` [*pass-by-reference*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
function if_exist(&$argument, $default="") {
   if(!isset($argument)) {
       $argument = $default;
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/mRce4NKa)

Comment: +1 because that's the only somewhat sensible thing to do. I don't think it's pretty or that it should be used, but rather relies on some of PHP's black magic.

Comment: @Andrew: That's not what I meant. The black magic is, that you can "pass an unidentified variable" without triggering some kind of error. but rather, PHP will silently initialize the variable in place with `null`.

Comment: For the record, your caps lock is on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of going at this. You may be looking for the first non-null value or if the actual variable is set or not...

The first use-case is easy... To get the value of the first variable that isn't null, define a function as such:

```
function coalesce() {
  $args = func_get_args();

  if(is_array($args))
    return null;

  foreach($args as $arg) {
    if($arg !== null)
      return $arg;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Using this function is easy. Simply call `coalesce()` with a number of different arguments and it will always return the first non-null value it encounters.

```
$myVar = coalesce($myVar, null, 'Hello There', 'World');
echo $myVar; // Hello there
```

---

However, if you are looking for a function to check if a variable is defined, and if it isn't define it, then you need to create a function which forces the first argument to be a reference.

```
function set_default(&$variable, $defaultValue = null) {
  if(!isset($variable)) {
    $variable = $defaultValue;

    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: No, `isset()` returns false when a variable is `null`. PS: You might want to name your function :) - the reason it must be a reference is, so PHP doesn't throw up on you and you can edit it of course while still having an effect in the calling scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you want a function for this at all.

```
$a = isset($a) ? $a : "my default string";
```

Everybody will understand what your code does without resorting to little-known "features" of PHP and having to look at your functions body to see what it does.

Even though it may look like a function call, it's not. [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is a *language construct*! That's why it will **not** raise a *Notice*.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function setGlobalIfNotSet( $variableName, $defaultValue = false ) {

  if ( ! isset( $variableName )) {

    global $$variableName;

    $$variableName = $defaultValue;

  }

}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., why double sigils (`$$`, `$$variableName`)? Why would it compile?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a function to use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
function isset_default($v, $default = '') {
    return isset($v) ? $v : $default;
}
```

Usage:

```
$v = isset_default($v, 'somedefaultvalue');
```

Comment: Heh, oops. After I realized he wanted a function I knew my answer was going to be bad