# php function for checking the existence of variable, if the variable doesn't exist then write a default value for the variable

Tags: php

i'm in need of a php function whose first argument will check that the variable exist or not outside of the function, if variable exist then echo it's value and if the variable doesn't exist then echo a default value for the variable given in second argument of the function. and in last remove(delete) both the variable passed to the function just after echoing their values.

simply :

```
function if_exists ($argument, $default)
{
// if $argument exist then echo it's value and then remove $argument variable.
// if the $argument doesn't exist then echo it's $default value and then remove $default variable.
}
```

i will use it like this :

```
$any_variable
if_exists ($any_variable, 'this variable is not defined');
```

this code is not doing the perfect job for me :

```
function if_exist(&$argument, $default = '')
{
    if (isset ($argument))
    {
        echo $argument;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $default;
        unset ($default);
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Why do you need it? How is this different from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654538/php-function-to-unset-variables-passed-by-reference  -- also: You cannot "delete" a variable in a different scope (except for the global scope).

Comment: that function doesn't work right for me, i need exactly the same thing i said in this question, please guide me if you can, i will appreciate your help, that code is bullshit for me, i need some fresh code of you guys.

Comment: You _will_ confuse yourself in (lets say) about 2 months, if a function called `if_exists()` outputs something and additional change the given arguments.

Comment: Pawan: In that case, update your question with code you have, that doesn't work. Tell us, what it does that you don't want it to, or rather: what you would like to have it do differently.

Comment: there are a lotttttttttttttttttt of variables , so i only need a funtion, through a function i could make change to all those variables at once , also the code will not look ugly.

Comment: Why don't you show us actual code and tell us why you think you need to perform such strange a thing.

Comment: i edited this post, check again.

Comment: And what isn't it doing for you? Note: You do *not* need to unset $default. That serves no purpose. Again: You are not telling us what you're trying to do, you are asking for a solution to make your solution work.

Comment: i'm just want to remove the variable $argument after echoing it's value, but making $argument = NULL; or $argument = ""; doesn't work for me, so i think this code will never work for me. :'(

Comment: No, you want to do that, because you *think* you need to do that. But what you really want to do, is solve a certain problem, for which you *believe* you have found a solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't work out as you would have liked, which is why we're having this conversation. Why can't you just tell us, what the **actual problem** is?

Comment: `
function if_exist(&$argument, $default = '')
{
 if (isset ($argument))
 {
  echo $argument;
  $argument = NULL;
 }
 else
 {
  echo $default;
  unset ($default);
 }
}
`
the $argument is not being null with this code, i want to delete the $argument totally from the script just after echoing it's value, it's a very simple question, why don't you guys understand it?

Comment: `code`
function if_exist(&$argument, $default = '')
{
 if (isset ($argument))
 {
  echo $argument;
  $argument = NULL;
 }
 else
 {
  echo $default;
  unset ($default);
 }
}
`code`
the $argument is not being null with this code, i want to delete the $argument totally from the script just after echoing it's value, it's a very simple question, why don't you guys understand it?

Comment: @Pawan: Can you edit your question instead please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function for this

```
$var = isset($var) ? $var : $default;
```

Comment: " and in last remove(delete) both the variable passed to the function just after echoing their values." See my answer to a slightly different question of his: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643692/php-function-to-check-variable-exist-or-not-outside-of-function/6643867#6643867

Comment: hi king, can you wrap you code in a fucntion, it will be a great help. thanks.

Comment: @Pawan: I have given you the exact same idiom (as linked above). It's not in a function because it shouldn't be in a function. I doubt KingCrunch will put it into a function for you.

Comment: Thats a one-liner and its already a simple operator of its own :? Why you need a function for it? Creating a function would mean, that you make just an alias.

Comment: yup i want to have a alias for it, please try to understand.

Comment: @Pawan: You cannot make this work through a function, all you can do is set it to null instead, but it will still be defined.

Comment: any other example code for a function except the one listed above? dear phant0m it's that function is not doing the job, i just want to remove the variable $argument after echoing it's value, this step is very important for me.